# .htaccess, make all urls without .html go to some php files and the ones without .html to a specific path

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to get a .htaccess file to work, here is what I need

`domain.com/some-slug-url should point to my_folder/display.php?page_url=$1`

and

`domain.com/some-other-url.html should point other specific rules`

Also there is an admin side so I would also need to have something like
domain.com/admin - load admin folder

I think there should be a condition like

if url does not end with `.html` or is not admin .. then `my_folder/display.php?page_url=$1`
The problem is that I am not an expert in .htaccess files, but I have tried to do this but with no luck, I know it's not that complicated but somewhere along the line I lose it and everything works except the `/some-slug-url`

Thank you
I've wasted a lot of time on this trying to get it going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewriteengine on

#this one is for /admin
rewriterule ^admin$ /admin [l]

#this one is for pages ending with .html
rewriterule ^(.*)\.html /my_folder/display.php?page_url=$1 [l]

#this one is for pages not ending with .html, and not for /admin
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /someotherpath
```

Note the use of the `[l]` parameter, which states that if that rule is matched, htaccess will not loop throught any other conditions.

Comment: the last rule is what I have tried before and it does not work and here is why: if the user is going to domain.com this should show the index page and in fact it loads the page that is supposed to load only for /some-url-here, the second thing is that I have other specific rewriterules that should be followed from old links like: ^this-link-1.html$ this-link.html, thank you for your fast reply still working on this, if I find a solution I will post it here

Comment: I've found the solution, the solution is that /admin and the other rules go at the top since the .htaccess is processed in recursive mode, them the last rule is something like: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/file.php?page_url=$1 [L]

Comment: I'm glad you've found the best solution for you. Thanks for the vote :).